# python connect to windows machine and execute commands remotely

Tags: python

i was trying to remote from a windows machine (this machine has python26 installed) to another windows machine (this machine doesnt has python installed) using python script. i googled through and found out that WMI module is very good. so i tried using this. below is my code :

```
    class WindowsMachine:
        def __init__(self, ip, username, password, remote_path=REMOTE_PATH):
            self.ip = ip
            self.username = username
            self.password = password
            self.remote_path = remote_path
            try:
                print "Establishing connection to %s" %self.ip
                self.connection = wmi.WMI(self.ip, user=self.username, password=self.password)
                print "Connection established"
            except wmi.x_wmi:
                print "Could not connect to machine"
                raise
```

but im getting error message : wmi.x_access_denied". i have googled up for a solution for this but didnt get a proper answer. can someone please help? anyone encountered this before?

Comment: hi, after connection established, i would like to have a certain check. such as checking in a certain folder if there are files available, checking ages of files that are in certain folder. is there a better way to do this? i do not want to use ssh as this would require me to install ssh in both windows pc's

Comment: hi there. im sorry, check update in your answer? where is the update please?

Comment: Are you including the domain for your user in the username? Like this auth_user = '{0}\{1}'.format(domain, user) then try connecting wmic = wmi.WMI(host_ip, user=auth_user, password=password)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is usually permission related. There is a [good article on troubleshooting WMI here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394603(v=vs.85).aspx). In addition to that, I recommend using [wmic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx) (the WMI command line client) to isolate the problem before going back to the Python code.

Here is an example of wmic failing due to the user not being authenticated:

```
C:> wmic /node:10.0.0.1 os get caption
Node - 10.0.0.1
ERROR:
Code = 0x80070005
Description = Access is denied.
Facility = Win32
```

Here is the same command, but this time it succeeds because the user is authenticated:

```
C:> wmic /node:10.0.0.1 /user:example\user /password:123456 os get caption
Caption
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Standard Edition
```

Comment: hi Rod, i tried this commands, and got the same "access is denied" description. im looking at the article now